# Windows Share Not Visible in Explorer But Can Still Ping The Server

Tags: windows-xp, windows-explorer

We have a network share on a server, call it foo. When trying to enter `\\foo\C$` in Windows explorer address bar, I get an error that the resource cannot be found. However, when I append the domain name, e.g., `\\foo.ene.com\C$` the right thing occurs.

The domain name searches are properly set in the network connection settings and pinging the server resolves correctly. I'm friggin baffled.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is this in a domain environment and are both machines members in the same domain?

Comment: That is indeed strange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So here's what I did that ended up fixing the problem, although I don't know why.

ipconfig /flushdns --no joy
give up the DHCP lease and get a new one --nada
reboot --zip
resetting the tcp/ip stack --FIXED

Any theories as to what happened here?

Comment: It may have re-registered your name with WINS.

Comment: GAHH I have this problem EVERY SINGLE DAY with Windows Vista on my wifi network at home. At work it's fine, but every single damn time I go home in the evening I have to reset the TCP/IP stack!

Comment: How do you reset the tcp/ip stack?</noob>

Answer (score 1):

Are you running WINS?  A short name can be looked up with WINS, where a long name will force DNS.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like yoour computer doesnt know on which dns domain it have to search for the server foo. Normaly the dns domain should be given by the dhcp server or the active directory (I'm not sure about that in windows domains).

I'm assuming you're using Windows XP. Try to add the dns domain by hand:
Open the Network Connection Propoerties of your LAN Adapter under start -> settings -> network connections. Mark "Internet protocol TCP/IP" and click on the button "Settings".

In the next dialog open "Advanced" under the Tab "DNS" mark the Option Append this DNS suffixes (in order)" and add the dns domain ene.com and apply the changes.

The windows share should be accessible over \foo\c$ now.

Comment: Sorry. Sometimes the question should be read exactly ;-)
Maybe a "ipconfig /flushdns" executed from command line helps.
What does the command "nslookup foo" respond?